# Error : Integrate firebase analytics with ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase Analytics with an Ionic 3 app and add Google-service files in the root of the application. However, I keep getting the below Error. Any idea what I maybe doing wrong?

> ERROR TypeError: this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(...).then is not a function
>       at RegistrationPage.webpackJsonp.103.RegistrationPage.ionViewDidEnter

**Registration.ts**

```
export class RegistrationPage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,  
private firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegistrationPage');
}

public ionViewDidEnter()
{
this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('page_view', {page: 
 'RegistrationPage'}).then((res: any) => {
  console.log(res)
})
.catch((error: any) => {
console.error(error)
});
}
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics';
....
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
FirebaseAnalytics
]
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?